# VS2019 c++ C3861 error in deep inheritance templates

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019

I'm getting a C3861 error with /permissive- compilations in VS2019 when I have a deep inheritance hierarchy with the most derived template accessing protected symbols from the root derived-from class

```
class BaseClass
{
protected:
    void baseClassMethod()
    {
        m_value = 0;
    }

    int m_value;
};

template<typename T1>
class DerTmpl_1 : public BaseClass
{
public:
    T1 doTheThing(T1 t)
    {
        baseClassMethod();
        m_value = 123;
        return t;
    }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class DerTmpl_2 : DerTmpl_1<T1>
{
public:
    T2 doTheOtherThing(T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        baseClassMethod();  // C3861 here, but only with /permissive-
        doTheThing(t1);     
        m_value = 456;      // C3861 here, but only with /permissive-
        return t2;
    }
};
```

Any guidance as to why DerTmpl_2::doTheOtherThing doesn't compile?

C3861 error output

```
1>C:\Users\kevin\source\repos\cpp17-permissiveMinusTest\cpp17-permissiveMinusTest\cpp17-permissiveMinusTest.cpp(35,3): error C3861:  'baseClassMethod': identifier not found
1>C:\Users\kevin\source\repos\cpp17-permissiveMinusTest\cpp17-permissiveMinusTest\cpp17-permissiveMinusTest.cpp(37,3): error C3861:  'm_value': identifier not found
```

Comment: What *is* error "C3861"? Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into the question body.

Comment: `:public DerTmpl_1<T1>`

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members

Comment: I'd just recommend not using the most recent versions of Visual Studio upon release. They're generally buggy and don't instantly support the most recent standards regardless.

Comment: updated with C3861 error output, per @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `this` to access data members of base class which depends on template parameter:

```
    this->baseClassMethod();  // C3861 here, but only with /permissive-
    doTheThing(t1);     
    this->m_value = 456;      // C3861 here, but only with /permissive-
```

Comment: Thanks - do you know if this is this only a requirement for indirectly inherited classes?

Comment: nvm, looks like the justification is listed above: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members from @aschepler

Answer (score 6):

Note that the issue has nothing to do with deep inheritance hierarchy, it might happen only when inheriting from class templates. Nondependent names won't be looked up in dependent base classes, on the other hand, [the lookup of a dependent name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#Lookup_rules) used in a template is postponed until the template arguments are known.

You need to make the names dependent for those from dependent base class (which depends on the template parameter `T1`), e.g.

```
this->baseClassMethod();
this->m_value = 456;
```

Or

```
BaseClass::baseClassMethod();
BaseClass::m_value = 456;
```